What are the settlement times trading futures in a cash account
So I’ve been trading options for almost a year now and have decided to give futures a try. I have a cash account not a margin and know that with options once I trade all the settled cash in my account I have to wait until it settles the next morning to use it again.
My question is I’ve heard that futures settle immediately but I can’t find out if that’s just with a margin account or with cash ones too. Can I buy $1000 worth of futures contracts at 9:30am sell them 5 minutes later and use whatever p/l I made to immediately place another trade at 9:40 or do I have to wait. (The times are just examples)

Within the same exchange the settlement to your margin account should be immediate. But for the authoritative answer, always refer to the exchange rules / documentation, as it's the exchange the creates and opertates the system.
